# Unable to download video file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using following code to download video file in ASP.net MVC but still unable to download.

```
public FileResult GetFile()
{
    string filename = string.Empty;
    byte[] file = null;
    string path = string.Empty;
    filename = "testVideo.mp4";
    path = Server.MapPath("location path here");
    System.IO.FileInfo fileinfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
    file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    return File(file, "content-disposition");
}
```

Comment: Doble check if you have rights to read on given location.

Comment: I checked with that path. I am able to play that file but unable to download that video. Even with same code I am able to download .ppt file.

Comment: please see my answer, hopefully its mime type needs to be added

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a MIME type as the second parameter of the File function:

```
return File(file, "video/mp4");
```

If you want to force the file to download, rather than be viewed, then you can also set the filename on it:

```
return File(file, "video/mp4", "myfilename.mp4");
```

Comment: I used this one also, but it's not working bro.

Comment: "Not working" doesn't help us provide suggestions.  You need to say what is not working, any error messages, and any other information.  We can't see your system!

Comment: I have looped this code in try and catch block. It's not throwing any exception, even last line which return statement has written there is executing properly but not showing pop window for download that video.

Comment: Try specifying the filename as per my update.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried this one also (return File(file, "video/mp4", "myfilename.mp4");). I am not getting download option.

Comment: What *are* you getting?

Comment: After line execution I am not getting anything.

Comment: Thank you Richard, actually I was calling this function from ajax call. So, I was getting problem. Now it's giving pop up window for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the server where you have hosted the application have the mime type of mp4 added or not.

If not then try to add its mime type in your web.config file so that the server can send this file as the response, add its mime type like below-

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```